# Program executes correctly on Ideone, but not in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I've just recently started re-learning C++ since learning it in high school in my spare time (using C++ Primer, 5th Ed.). As I was going through the basic exercises, I noticed the following program would not execute correctly in Xcode, but would execute correctly on Ideone: http://ideone.com/6BEqPN

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // currVal is the number we're counting; we'll read new values into val
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;

    // read first number and ensure that we have data to process
    if (std::cin >> currVal) {
        int cnt = 1;
        while (std::cin >> val) {
            if (val == currVal)
                ++cnt;
            else {
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times." << std::endl;
                currVal = val;
                cnt = 1;
            }
        }
        std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In XCode, the program does not finish. It stops in the last execution of the while loop body. In the debug console, I see that there is a signal SIGSTOP.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbD2J.png)

This is my first time using Xcode for any sort of IDE. I suspect it may have to do with my build settings? I've configured it for GNU++11 and to use libstdc++.

I'd appreciate any insight as to why this code would work on Ideone, but not on Xcode. Also, I was wondering what IDEs are preferred and if Xcode would be suitable for learning C++11. Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is with interactive input vs input *"closed"*.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cin` never stops. Your `while` loop's condition is `std::cin >> val`, so the loop will run until something that is not a number is input. After your input line (`42 42 42 42 42 55 55 62 100 100 100`) is processed, `cin` is *not* in a fail state, it just waits for new input. If you enter anything that is not a number, your loop will finish correctly (e.g. `42 42 42 42 42 55 55 62 100 100 100 x`).

If you want to read a single line of input, you should use `std::getline` and `stringstream`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    // currVal is the number we're counting; we'll read new values into val
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;

    string str;
    //read the string
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    //load it to the stream
    std::stringstream ss(str);

    //now we're working with the stream that contains user input
    if (ss >> currVal) {
        int cnt = 1;
        while (ss >> val) {
            if (val == currVal)
                ++cnt;
            else {
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times." << std::endl;
                currVal = val;
                cnt = 1;
            }
        }
        std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An other way to stop is to close input, which happens when use as `echo 42 42 42 42 42 55 55 62 100 100 100 | my_prog`.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall would it skip the loop without user enters a number? if the condition was.. `(std::cin >> val && val)`